# Countably compact implies convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $(X,d)$ be a metric space $K \subset X$ be countably compact.

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $K$

if $y$ is an accumulation point of the set $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$

show that $(x_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $y$

so what I have so far is that $y = x_k$ for some $k \geq 1$

and there is a sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $y$ and for each $i$

$$y_i = x_j $$ for some $j$.

We can assume that each $y_i$ is distinct but I'm not sure where to go from here

Also, I'm not sure how to use the fact that $K$ is countably compact

btw I need to show that $(x_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $y$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to show that there is a subsequence converging to $y$

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is **First Countable.**

Since the set $A=\{x_k:k\ge 1\}$ has $y$ as its accumulation point so there exists a sequence say $u_n\in A$  such that $u_n\to y$.

And since $u_n\to y$ every subsequence of $u_n$ say $v_n$ converges to $y$.

Also $v_n$ being  a subsequence of $u_n$ forms a subsequence of $x_n$ converging to $y$.